# Snapdragon SoC includes cellular modem RF. Does it still need a baseband CPU?

Tags: integrated-circuit, system-on-chip

As per https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon-425-mobile-platform
, the Snapdragon 425 includes cellular modem RF, WiFi, Bluetooth and GPS.

- Does that mean that it does not need a baseband CPU, or dedicated IC for WiFi/Bluetooth and GPS?
- Can anybody who wants to design a PXB include it is his design? How to obtain drivers / firmware for the components like the SoC itself and other ICs to include in Linux driver and build Android?

Comment: Hi, can you ask *one* question per question post, please? You ask at least two, and it would be better if you split these!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Snapdragon 425 contains the RF part of those interfaces and the logic to retrieve/encode data.

A base band CPU is still needed to process and present data to the user.

Possibly, the base band CPU and the RF modems are packaged together on the same chip.

---

Device drivers of consumer electronics chips like that Snapdragon are not open source. They are developed and optimized by Google or by Qualcomm or by Linaro or by some specialized third party authorized software house.

If you want to build your own Android or Linux device join one of the following open source projects:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_mobile_phones

---

Android is built on Linux but the user interface and many device drivers are written by Google mostly in C.

Google is developing Fuchsia which, nobody knows when, should replace the Linux part of Android.

Google's newest Nest Hub is the first product running Fuchsia OS.

Take a look here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchsia_(operating_system)